# C2871, C3861 в проекте

Tags: c++-cli

Не пойму откуда ноги растут, отладчик студии от C++ - из каменного века... Понимаю что ошибка моя, но студия выдает полную ахинею...

.cpp:

```
// Helper.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Helper.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>

namespace NativeCpp
{
    System::String^ GetMyString()
    {
        System::String^ str = "MyString";
        return str;
    }
}
```

.h:

```
// Helper.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace NativeCpp;

namespace Helper 
{
    public ref class Foundation
    {
        public: static String^ CheckStr()
        {
            String^ result = GetMyString();
            return result;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: а в чём именно проблема?

Comment: @pavel, ну судя по заголовку - в компиляции. C2871, C3861. Насколько помню - с префикса С начинаются коды ошибок в студии для натива...

Comment: Полный текст ошибок бы посмотреть... Ну и отладчик не при чем, приведенные ошибки не позволили бы ему запуститься.

Comment: Отладчик в студии один из самых лучших, если не лучший. Чего только стоит возможность остановить программу, поменять на лету код, и продолжить выполнение.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала идёт #include включение файла. То есть на месте include вставляется содержимое указанного файла.

Получается у тебя вот такой код.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace NativeCpp;

namespace Helper 
{
    public ref class Foundation
    {
        public: static String^ CheckStr()
        {
            String^ result = GetMyString(); //откуда взять GetMyString???
            return result;
        }

    };
}
namespace NativeCpp
{
    System::String^ GetMyString()
    {
        System::String^ str = "MyString";
        return str;
    }
}
```